# python requests gives 'None' response, where json data is expected

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

Firstly, I should add that you can find this request by doing the following:

```
1- Go to [airline site][1]
2- Type in "From" = "syd"
3- Type in "To" = "sin"
4- Make the departure date sep.3 and click one-way and search
5- On the search result page check your network get request when you click on an available seat option radio button
```

I'm trying to use the requests module to get the response for example from [this site](http://www.singaporeair.com/chooseFlightJson.form?tripType=O&selectedFlightIdDetails[0]=0%7CFF31SYD&hid_recommIDs=&userPreferedCurrency=&hid_flightIDs=)

And this is what I'm trying:

```
url = "http://www.singaporeair.com/chooseFlightJson.form?"
payload = {'selectedFlightIdDetails[0]':amount_data,'hid_flightIDs':'','hid_recommIDs':'','tripType':"O",'userPreferedCurrency':""}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print response.json()
```

The response is supposed to be:

```
{"price":{"total":"595.34","currency":{"code":"AUD","label":""},"adult":{"count":1,"label":"Adult","cost":"328.00","total":"328.00"},"child":{"count":0,"label":"Child","cost":"0.00","total":"0.00"},"infant":{"count":0,"label":"Infant","cost":"0.00","total":"0.00"},"addOns":[{"label":"Airport / Government taxes ","cost":"83.24"},{"label":"Carrier Surcharges","cost":"184.10"}],"disclaimer":"Prices are shown in Canadian Dollar(CAD)","rate":"595.34 AUD \u003d 913.80 CAD","ratehint":"Estimated","unFormattedTotal":"595.34"},"messages":{"O3FF11SYD":"A few seats left","O1FF31SYD":" ","R0FF31SYD":"A few seats left","O2FF31SYD":"A few seats left","O0FF31SYD":" ","O1FF11SYD":"A few seats left","O0FF21SYD":" ","O2FF21SYD":" ","O3FF21SYD":" ","O1FF21SYD":" "},"cabinClass":{"onwardCabin":["Economy"]}}
```

Comment: The response **is** the value `None`, encoded in JSON; the server returns `null\r\n`.

Comment: If you are expecting the string `null`, maybe you're looking for `response.content`. If you're expecting an empty dict json, null == None != {}

Comment: Updated the question, added the expected result, and the procedure you have to follow to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use requests session, like so:

```
session = requests.Session()
```

Then to call all of the urls you need to simply do:

```
response = session.get(url)
```

This sets the cookies and session variables which are necessary to retrieve the data.
I have seen jsessionid used in different ways, in the url, or in this case in a cookie. But there are probably other session info that are required, which is taken care of by a requests session object.

Answer (score 2):

The response **is** the value `None`, encoded in JSON; the server returns `null\r\n`, which means the same as `None` in Python.

The content type is wrong here; it is set to text/html, but the `response.json()` return value is entirely correct for what the server sent:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.singaporeair.com/chooseFlightJson.form?"
>>> amount_data = 0
>>> payload = {'selectedFlightIdDetails[0]':amount_data,'hid_flightIDs':'','hid_recommIDs':'','tripType':"O",'userPreferedCurrency':""}
>>> response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
>>> response
<Response [200]>
>>> response.headers['content-type']
'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'
>>> response.text
'null\r\n'
>>> response.json() is None
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Change protocol from `http` to `https`:

```
url = "https://www.singaporeair.com/chooseFlightJson.form?"
```

Answer (score 0):

while making http request make sure that **response_type** set to exact use case you are trying with.
In my case **response_type='object'** worked to eliminate None type in response.